# References issue with Xamarin.iOS project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.iOS project in my solution in Visual Studio 2015. It references other C# Library projects in the same solution that target .NET 4.5. Sometimes the references to these projects become broken (with the small yellow icon on the reference) and I can't build the project anymore, and I fix it by deleting the references, re-adding it, cleaning the solution (several times) until I can build it again (but the yellow icon on the reference is always visible). Has anyone had this problem before? It's rather annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. My other C# library projects that my Xamarin.iOS project was trying to reference were not PCL. Changing them to PCL solved this issue.